# get the id based on condition in group by

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to create a sql query to merge rows where there are equal dates. the idea is to do this based on the highest amount of hours, so that i in the end gets the corresponding id for each date with the highest amount of hours. i've been trying to do with a simple group by, but does not seem to work, since i CANT just put a aggregate function on `id` column, since it should be based the hours condition

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | date           | hours                       |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 2012-01-01     | 37                          |
| 2    | 2012-01-01     | 10                          |
| 3    | 2012-01-01     | 5                           |
| 4    | 2012-01-02     | 37                          |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

desired result

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | date           | hours                       |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 2012-01-01     | 37                          |
| 4    | 2012-01-02     | 37                          |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I added the greatest-n-per-group tag. This question has been asked in different forms hundreds of times, and there are many solutions. Some depend on the specific brand of RDBMS you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exactly one row -- even if there are ties -- then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by date order by hours desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Ironically, both Postgres and Oracle (the original tags) have what I would consider to be better ways of doing this, but they are quite different.

Postgres:

```
select distinct on (date) t.*
from t
order by date, hours desc;
```

Oracle:

```
select date, max(hours) as hours,
       max(id) keep (dense_rank first over order by hours desc) as id
from t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using `row_number`:

```
select id, dt, hours
from (
    select id, dt, hours, row_number() over (partition by dt order by hours desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery with *correlation* approach :

```
select t.*
from table t
where id = (select t1.id
            from table t1
            where t1.date = t.date
            order by t1.hours desc
            limit 1);
```

In *Oracle* you can use `fetch first 1 row only` in `subquery` instead of `LIMIT` clause.